# How Can I Draw Lines in Webforms?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I need draw lines from one point to another point in Web Forms. Can I do that on a Panel?  If not, what should I use? A canvas? Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using css using adjusting div with position.

Like

```
.line{
width: 112px; /*Width of line*/
height: 10px;
border-bottom: 1px solid black; /*Adjust top or bottom*/
position: absolute;
}


<div class="line"></div>
```